# Typescript object property from type definiton

Tags: typescript

I'll describe the problem as simply as possible

I have a type composed of forced strings eg:

```
type myType = 'name' | 'age' | 'family' | 'other';
```

I'm going to create a type that forces me to write this

```
const myObject: myCastType<myType> = {
    name: 'string',
    age: 'string',
    family: 'string',
    other: 'string',
}
```

so what I would like to create `myCastType`

what I'm missing is the step that allows me to force an object to be composed of properties called by the passed types

to make you understand better I'm not interested in being able to create a type eg:

```
type Person = { name: string, age: string, family: string, other: string }

const myObject: Person = { ... }
```

My problem is that props like 'name', 'age', etc... don't know them and they change in the various implementation i want to do so i need to define them dynamically

I tried to search for something about it but no one mentions my problem or anything similar, but unfortunately I haven't found anything that can help me.

of course I tried things like Pick, Record, Extract, etc, basically a good part of those present on 'lis.es5.d.ts'

Does anyone have any ideas or can direct me to a more correct path. links, documentation or any material is welcome

Comment: *"I have a type composed of forced strings eg:"* That's called a *string literal union* (a union of string literal types).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be glad to know that the "cast type" already exists — `Record`:

```typescript
type MyType = "name" | "age" | "family" | "other";

const myObject: Record<MyType, string> = {
    name: "string",
    age: "string",
    family: "string",
    other: "string",
};
```

`Record<MyType, string>` means "a record (object) with the property names from `MyType` [which can a a simple type or a union] and the values `string`."

If you left out any of those properties, TypeScript would complain the object wasn't valid.

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq5oF4oCIB2BDAthNUAPulgOb5HoBmuAlgDYgHFoD2wAFhAE5oDcAKAEBjVhgDOwKDhAB5AEYArCMOAAuKACUVrbgBMAPHESQANFEndaGUgD4oqAN4CorqNjwa0l66TSmXNzIILx8bf0DXGhwGEFDgK3CAtyh2Lm54xL8AgF9BAQB6AqgAEQgcMUssYF8oTmgebl01EUqpawA3LHpaPQVlVQ1tUX0jBCRzMLsHKGcUjxD0KYiU4MzfFbdo2PWkgTygA)